# Ubuntu low disk space because of many unused partitions

Tags: disk-usage

I'm using ubuntu via dual-boot, and i've allocated about 22GB for it.

I've got a massage that the disk-space is low (250MB left), and when I run `df -h`, the result is:

[image: Here]

It seems that I have a lot of disk space but in different partitions. Is there anything that I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, they are system partitions, not for data storage. You can't use them. They are not real. They are created on boot and destroyed on shutdown. Looks like you've allocated about 10GB for Ubuntu and its almost full.

Comment: When I did the "shrink" thing, I allocated 22,000 MB - about 22 GB. But when I press 'About this computer' it says I have 10.GB disk. Where did I go wrong? Can I allocate more without uninstalling it?

Comment: Try using a GUI to `parted` such as `gparted` (`sudo apt install gparted; gksudo gparted`, use kdesudo instead of gksudo if on KDE). This will list all the storage devices on your machine as well as all the partitions. It may be that when you installed you created a data partition (space on a disk) but you haven't `mount`ed that space, kinda like not unlocking a filing cabinet draw. Parted is very powerful and can seriously mess up your system -- including deleting all your files -- RTFM (read the manual!) first.

Answer (score 0):

> What I did wrong?

Did you defragment your hard drive before shrinking? If you have 30GB free space on disk it **doesn't** mean you will be able to shrink out 30GB because of fragmented files.

You will have to reinstall. But before that make sure you have enough space as unallocated space atleast 20gb for a usable system. Did you check your partition size after shrinking?

After reading your comments, its clear that you havent allocated 22GB for Ubuntu. You allocated 12GB for swap area. **Swap is not a part of Ubuntu**, its a shared area that is used only when RAM is about to fill. Any OS that supports swapping will use the swap area. Since swap is not a part of any OS, it is not showed when you type `df` on terminal. You can use GParted to see all partitions of your disk.

Tip: You dont need 12GB of swap. 2GB is sufficient for computers with 4+ GB RAM.

Comment: I didn't did it before shrinking. My partition size is 23 GB. But about 12 GB goes for the swap partition

Comment: Swap is not shared with your OS. You gave 12 gb for swap from 22gb memory so ubuntu can use only 10gb for system. BTW, you dont need 12gb for swap. 2gb is sufficient. Infact from ubuntu 17 onwards you dont need a swap area at all.

Comment: I didn't choose to give the swap 12GB, it just happend (maybe bacause I have 12GB of RAM?). Anyway, Do you know how can I change the swap to 2GB without any risky changes?

Comment: You can format swap again with GParted from a live Ubuntu CD (not from installed OS) Allocate 2GB to swap and format the remaining 10 GB as NTFS. You can use the NTFS partition for storing documents and media and free up space from system. Its not possible to increase system partition size without formatting. Its best to reinstall but reduce swap size next time. Ubuntu's installer allows to do that from GUI :)

Comment: I think you should update your question with all the info you gave in comments